# Arduino IDE has no shortcut in openSUSE

Tags: arduino-ide, linux

I just installed the Arduino IDE in openSUSE 13.1. I am able to open the application using the run dialogue, so I know it has installed. However, there is no way to open the IDE from any application launcher. I have tried both the Kickoff and Lancelot applciation managers. I have also tried to uninstall and re-install the IDE, both through the 1-click on the Arduino website as well as through the command line.

Does anyone know why I am unable to launch the application from the launcher? Thanks in advanced for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this seems to work. If you right click on the Kickoff Application launcher and open 'edit applications' with KDE Menu Editor, you can 'add new item' where you want and give it a name (ArduinoIDE) and then just put arduino (small case) in the 'command' box, and shut down KDE Menu Editor, it should appear in the menu where ever you placed it. At least it did for me.